# exp:playa:parents not returning parents

Tags: playa

I have two channels:

- locations
- meetup

"meetup" has a playa field called {chapter_affiliation}

I have one entry in "meetup" with the playa field selecting one location.

I'm using EE 2.7.0 and Playa 4.4.5 (fresh install of Playa).

The following templates are copy pasted from the real templates.

My template for "meetup" properly shows the affiliated chapter using this code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel='meetup'}
    {exp:playa:children field="chapter_affiliation"}
    <div><a href="/locations/{url_title}">Affiliated Chapter {title}</a></div>
    {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

My template for "locations" will not show the parent "meetup" and I've been staring at it for so long, I can't see why not. The following template will list all the locations, but nothing lists underneath any location, despite the above template properly showing the affiliation.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="locations"}
    <h3>As Seen in {title}</h3>
    <ul>
    {exp:playa:parents channel="meetup"}
        <li><a href="{path={channel_short_name}/{url_title}}">{title}</a></li>
    {/exp:playa:parents}
    </ul>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

My question is: What have I done wrong and how can I fix it.

Comment: Try adding `field="chapter_affiliation"` to your `parents` tag.

Comment: Also check `var_prefix` here http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/parents.html - your inner loop may be calling the wrong fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your Meetup entry have an 'open' Status? An Entry Date in the past? No expiration date, or one set in the future? By default Playa will only show entries that meet those criteria, and if you want anything different you will need to specify the `status=`, `show_future_entries=`, and `show_expired=` params, just like with [{exp:channel:entries}](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#parameters).

Comment: This was it! I had the entry set to a future date!